# FFMpeg 3.4 with NDK 15c vs FFMpeg 3.4 with NDK 16b

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I compiled FFMpeg under revision 15c, does it make sense to collect it on revision 16b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you want to use updated tools (compiler, etc.). It will stay perfectly compatible without rebuilding.